# Chat application like facebook using ajax

Tags: ajax

I want to develop a chat application like facebook. I did this and now it works fine. I used ajax for continuing server request to save and retrieve data. One function which is called each 10 second:

```
// Load  message
(function loadClient() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'c_id=' + $.cookie("c_id") + '&offset=' + $('#c_name_msgHead').data('offset'), //'foo='+ bar+'&calibri='+ nolibri,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: $("#webroot").text() + 'chats/loadMsg',
        success: function (data) {
            var id =0;
              if ($.cookie("status") == "active"){

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                    if(item.Chat.status == 'active'){
                        $('.temp_msg').remove();
                    }

                    if (!$('#' + item.Chat.id)[0]) {
                        if (item.Chat.admin_message) {
                            $('<div class="msg_b" id="' + item.Chat.id + '">' + item.Chat.admin_message + '</div>').insertBefore('.client_area .msg_push');
                        }
                        if (item.Chat.client_message) {
                            $('<div class="msg_a" id="' + item.Chat.id + '">' + item.Chat.client_message + '</div>').insertBefore('.client_area .msg_push');
                        }
                        $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
                    }


                 id = item.Chat.id;
            });

            $('#c_name_msgHead').data('offset', id);

              } 


        },
        complete: function () {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            setTimeout(loadClient, 3000);
        }
    });
})();
// END load message
```

It load update data after 10 second. Now if there are 10000 users at a time 10000 request will be send to my server which is a concerned of performance and shutdown of server may occur. Even if 10000 users did not start chatting 10000 request will be performed. So what should I do to develop such application which need to tiger server continuously or which technology is used for facebook chatting. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is using the technique called **Long Polling**.
However,for chatroom with high respond rate, it is strongly suggested and much better to use socket.io with node.js as your server side which makes use of sockets to achieve most realtime bi-directional communication channel between a client and a server.

You can read the following tutorial as your starting point

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/